# iOS: Remove app rating limit for developer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appirater

I want to test my app's `SKStoreReviewController` API rating. However, I believe it is block because I exceeded the three time review limit a year. Is there a way around this for a developer? Here is the code I am using currently.

```
    [Appirater setAppId:kAppId];
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:10];
    [Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
    [Appirater setDebug:NO];
    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Appirater documentation](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater#development), you have to turn the debug mode on to show the request every time in development:

```
[Appirater setDebug:YES];
```

Comment: Is there a way without setting debug to Yes?

Comment: The debug mode is here to do exactly what you asked. When you are done testing, turn it off before release.